# Forcing Code in Ruby on Windows when X button is hit

Tags: ruby, windows

While writing a ruby script on Windows (ruby -v outputs ruby 1.9.3p545) I encountered an interesting and rather specific problem. I was attempting to close an opened file if a user terminates execution. For example,

```
begin
f = File.open("monkeys.txt", "w+")
#stuff with the file
rescue Exception => e #I know this is a bad idea
puts e.backtrace
ensure
f.close
end
```

Now, this works if I terminate execution via Ctrl+C while running this in cmd. However, when I hit the "X" on the cmd prompt window, the code in the ensure block doesn't run. I tried something like...

```
at_exit do
f.close if !f.closed?
end
```

...but that still doesn't execute the code I want it to when the X button is hit. 
So, what do I do in order to force "ensure" code in Ruby if it's closed via that X button?

Comment: I would think that closing the `CMD` window will (force) kill any processes running via CMD. That would mean that ruby has no way of rescuing since the process does not get to shutdown.

Comment: But of course the OS will close any open files and release all memory when it terminates a process anyway.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Does that mean there's nothing I can do about it?
EDIT: Well, to be more exact, I'm writing a script that appends RNG output to a text file. I'm trying to make it so that even if the user X'es out the application, the latest output is still written to the file.

Comment: As a plain cmd shell program no.   If you used something that actually ran as a windows application that speaks the windows API, which creates its own window and responds to the window close event generated by clicking the x.  Google for `ruby windows gui` for that, I can't help.

Comment: if you keep flushing the buffers then even if you are not able to handle the window close, chances that the data will end up in the file is higher.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really program for windows, so I might get lost on the details, but let me try to shed some light with this workaround for Linux:

```
@ppid = Process.ppid
pid = fork do
  loop do
    sleep(1)
    begin
      Process.getsid(@ppid)
    rescue Errno::ESRCH
      File.new("process_down.txt", "a+")
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end

Process.detach(pid)
puts "Process detached"
```

What this does is it creates a forked process, detaches it from the main process and keeps listening for when the main process is killed (it'll throw Errno::ESRCH on Process.getsid if the @ppid is no longer there), so it'll create a .txt file and exit. I don't know how to handle forking and pids in windows, but that's just to try and show you some possibilities =]